# Video/Audio out of sync when recording with java code

Tags: java, audio, video, synchronization, delay

I created **java app** which **captures video from webcam and analog audio** from e-drums at the same time. Next step should be simultaneous capturing of midi signal (via usb) but this not the point for the time being.

I noticed **increasing delay of video (behind audio) over time**, after 90 minutes of capturing the delay is already a couple of seconds. Similar delay occurs if I capture webcam audio signal instead of external e-drums.

Audio is recorded into separate wav file with jawax.sound API as a separate thread.
Video is recorded into separate mp4 file using IMediaWriter (xuggler code) as a separate thread.
Webcam is accessed by sarxos code.

My **code** (relevant part) is here:

```
public class VideoAudioCapture {
    TargetDataLine line;
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
    File wavFile = null;
    File mp4File = null;
    File csvFile = null;
    public static IMediaWriter writer;
    Webcam webcam;

    webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(size);
    //webcam.open();      

    public void run(){
        
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            //Prepare files for writing
            String prefix = "D:/";
            wavFile = new File(prefix + "/RecordAudio" + "_" + timeStamp + ".wav");
            mp4File = new File(prefix + "/RecordVideo" + "_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            csvFile = new File(prefix + "/RecordVideo" + "_" + timeStamp + ".csv");
            
            //Starts 2 threads, for mp4 and wav separate capture
            Runnable mp4Task = new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            startRecordMp4();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(WebcamGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(WebcamGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                };
            Thread t3 = new Thread(mp4Task);
            t3.start();
            
            Runnable wavTask = new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        startRecordWav();
                    }
                };
                Thread t2 = new Thread(wavTask);
                t2.start();
    }

    public void startRecordWav(){
        int selectedMixerIndex = jComboBoxAudioInput.getSelectedIndex();
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[ selectedMixerIndex ]);
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100.0F, 16, 2, true, false); 
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info( TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat );
        try {
            line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            line.open();
            line.start();
            System.out.println("Audio line microsecond position = " + line.getMicrosecondPosition());
             AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
                    try {
                        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);
                        System.out.println("AudioSystem frame length = " + ais.getFrameLength());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(WebcamGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
            } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebcamGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void startRecordMp4() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(mp4File.getAbsolutePath());
        FileWriter csvfileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile);
        csvfileWriter.append("time (ms)" + "," + "video - audio delay (ms)");
        csvfileWriter.append("\n");
        
        Dimension size = WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize();
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);        
        
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000;
        long len = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000 - time;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

            System.out.println("Line microsecon position = " + (long) (line.getMicrosecondPosition())/1000);
            System.out.println("Video time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            System.out.println("Video - audio delay = " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)-(long) (line.getMicrosecondPosition())/1000));
            IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start ) * 1000);
            frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
            frame.setQuality(100);
            writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long runningTime = (currentTime - startTime);
            String iString = String.valueOf(i);
            if (iString.endsWith("0")){
                csvfileWriter.append(String.valueOf(runningTime) + "," + String.valueOf(((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)-(long) (line.getMicrosecondPosition())/1000)));
                csvfileWriter.append("\n");
            }
            String fps = String.format("%.2f", webcam.getFPS());
            System.out.println("Current fps = " + fps);
            if(jButtonCapture.getModel().isPressed())
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
        writer.close();
        line.stop();
        line.close();

        csvfileWriter.flush();
        csvfileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I did some digging and tracked how the delay evolves in time: I defined delay as actual "video timestamp" - actual "audio time stamp" = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) - (long) (line.getMicrosecondPosition())/1000. Then I plotted **delay values over time** and got these steps (no smooth curve):
[Plot of delay values in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aignd.png)

I have a few **questions** related to my issue:

1. Where does the delay come from? Is it because different HW has different internal clocking?
2. How to interpret/understand step-looking plot of delay in time?
3. How to deal with the issue? There must be a way, there are tons of video/audio apps around with no noticeable delay.
4. I already tried an alternative of capturing audio as a track into mp4 file (via writer.encodeAudio(...) and audio samples) - delay appeared as well

Thank you for any tips/answers.

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this is helpful or not, but the only way I've been able to maintain accurate timing (e.g., wrote a decent metronome, have audio coordinated with graphics updates) was to count frames at the point closest to the system. For audio output, that's in a routine that outputs bytes to a `SourceDataLine`. The `write()` method blocks, and so, is the point most closely tied to the rate at which the system will consume the audio data. This has provided the best "real time" results I've found.

Timings are then calculated by multiplying the number of frames against the frame rate.

Given Java's multi-threading (cpu managing multiple task streams), Java doesn't provide "real-time guarantees". IDK if this is the source of the slippage you are experiencing.

I haven't dealt with video, but I'm thinking it must also have a defined frame rate. Perhaps you can create a unit of work, with a set of buffer dimensions where audio and video processing of incoming data are yoked together? A form of loose coupling and buffering could be used to provide the source data to that yoke point so the individual vagaries of processor timing of the two streams don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Phil. Since I posted the issue I set each video frame to be written wrt current audio time stamp, i.e. considering delay = actual "video timestamp" - actual "audio time stamp" which I used for tracking delay before. Now I am getting so to say perfect synchronization although I am not sure how safe this method is. I should try counting frames as well. Btw, in my case it looks like audio timing is faster than system's, I will have to check on this. Video fps is defined by webcam, I don't think I can do much about it (e.g. it depends on light conditions).

Comment: System clock was inadequate to the task of providing metronomic precision with audio. Maybe this doesn't apply to your use case. A good backgrounder on "Real Time Low Latency Audio in Java" hosted by University of Michigan is in pdf form at the following location. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131